# How to unload and load classes in clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to load and unload java classes programmatically? For instance, can I use pomegranate to download a dependency that is already existing and reload all the classes for that library?

Comment: Where is the Clojure part in your question?

Comment: A java class is also a clojure class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Short, Yes. pomegranate can be used to change dependency versions and such at runtime.
It's a decent enough tool for this sort of interactive programming. Certainly better than playing with [classloaders](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077260/learn-java/the-basics-of-java-class-loaders.html) directly

Comment: Thanks arthur, Would you be able to provide an example of this and maybe some limitations of pomegranate if any?